# how to remove space between rows using bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, padding

I wanted to remove space between `rows` i.e. `Payment received` and `balance payment`. I tried using `nopadding`, `row-bottom-margin` to the `row` but it didn't worked. I don't know why space is coming in between. I am new to bootstrap.

[image]

Code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">      
        <div class="col-md-12" style="font-size:15px;padding-top:0px;font-family:Calibri;margin-left:60px;">
            Payment Receieved : <asp:Label 
            ID="lblPayReceive" runat="server" CssClass="lblDeadln" ></asp:Label>
        </div>                 
    </div>

    <div class="row">               
        <div class="col-md-12" style="font-size:15px;padding-top:0!important;font-family:Calibri;margin-left:60px;">
            Balance Payment : <asp:Label 
            ID="lblBalance" runat="server" CssClass="lblDeadln" ></asp:Label>
        </div>
    </div>    
</div>
```

Comment: `row` doesn't have bottom `margin` or `padding`, some other class is causing the space in this case, what is `row-bottom-margin` for?

Comment: .row-bottom-margin { margin-bottom:10px; }

Comment: remove `row-bottom-margin` ?! Also  `<div class="col-md-12">` seems unnecessary

Comment: i removed but still the space is coming

Comment: Inspect the elements and check what is causing it

Comment: i have just edited the changes

Comment: row class does not create margin/padding top or bottom. Some other css is causing it.

Comment: line-height property affects it. please remove it from body tag...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify the line-height property for the text...

Please check **[this](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/65135/)**

```
body {
  margin: 10px;
  line-height:0.6;
}
```